# Docker seccomp works for alpine/busybox but not ubuntu

Tags: docker, security, ubuntu

I have this seccomp profile:

```
{
"defaultAction": "SCMP_ACT_ALLOW",
"architectures": [
    "SCMP_ARCH_X86_64",
    "SCMP_ARCH_X86",
    "SCMP_ARCH_X32"
],
"syscalls": [
    {
        "name": "chmod",
        "action": "SCMP_ACT_ERRNO",
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "name": "chown",
        "action": "SCMP_ACT_ERRNO",
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "name": "chown32",
        "action": "SCMP_ACT_ERRNO",
        "args": []
    } }
```

When using this to filter syscalls on alpine or busybox containers, it works

```
docker run -it --security-opt seccomp=profile.json busybox /bin/sh
// chmod 777 /etc/hosts
// Error: operation not permitted
```

But it has no effect on ubuntu:18.04

```
docker run -it --security-opt seccomp=profile.json ubuntu:18.04 /bin/sh
// chmod 777 /etc/hosts
// Success
```

Docker version is 19.03.8

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docker-lab](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/labs/master/security/seccomp/seccomp-profiles/default-no-chmod.json), its seems you missing two more property to make it working with Linux properly

> The default-no-chmod.json profile is a modification of the default.json profile> with the `chmod()`, `fchmod()`, and `chmodat()` syscalls removed from its whitelist.

[image]
[security-seccomp](https://training.play-with-docker.com/security-seccomp/)

```
{
"defaultAction": "SCMP_ACT_ALLOW",
"architectures": [
    "SCMP_ARCH_X86_64",
    "SCMP_ARCH_X86",
    "SCMP_ARCH_X32"
],
"syscalls": [
    {
        "name": "chmod",
        "action": "SCMP_ACT_ERRNO",
        "args": []
    },
      {
        "name": "fchmod",
        "action": "SCMP_ACT_ERRNO",
        "args": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "fchmodat",
        "action": "SCMP_ACT_ERRNO",
        "args": [

        ]
      },
    {
        "name": "chown",
        "action": "SCMP_ACT_ERRNO",
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "name": "chown32",
        "action": "SCMP_ACT_ERRNO",
        "args": []
    }] 
}
```

Now if you tried from ubuntu you will get expected result

```
docker run -it --security-opt seccomp=profile.json ubuntu:18.04 /bin/sh -c " chmod +x /etc/hosts"

chmod: changing permissions of '/etc/hosts': Operation not permitted
```

Also, same result for busybox

```
docker run -it --security-opt seccomp=profile.json busybox /bin/sh -c " chmod +x /etc/host"
chmod: /etc/host: No such file or directory
```